# Multi-layered child viewcontrollers where delegation is becoming a nightmare - how should they communicate with each other?

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

This is a serious problem for me right now. Working on a code base with multi-layered children viewcontrollers about 4-5 layers deep - this is a tablet app with a very high degree of decoupling between viewcontrollers. The 5th layer child viewcontroller wants to send a message to the top level viewcontroller to show a modal. The 4th layer and 3rd layer have different messages as well so basically now I have like 4 protocols and its getting pretty complicated to send messages from such child viewcontrollers nested deep within to an ancestor viewcontroller. Is there an easier way to do this?

We thought about using NSNotification but not particularly fond of it because of its difficulty in debugging it and subscription not being a clear dependency within our control. We also thought about using a singleton but statics and singletons are evil (right?) and cause problems around state and concurrency.

Any help is appreciated. Also I realize I realize this is a slightly open ended design based question but it has a very specific use case (like the one described above).

Comment: What do you mean by " multi-layered children viewcontrollers about 4-5 layers deep"? Are you talking about a navigation controller stack? Also, do controllers 3,4, and 5 only need to communicate with 1, or do they communicate with each other as well.

Comment: A->child view controller of B-> child view controller of C-> child view controller of D. Something happens in D which it needs to tell A about. Conventional delegation dictates D's protocol implemented by A and D delegates it to C->B->A OR A is passed all the way along to D which it can delegate to. Problem is all these viewcontrollers talk to the A and each other and hence I have like 4-5 different protocols which have intersections of some common methods and some different ones - basically creating a mess. Better way to do this with multi-layered child viewcontrollers?

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the controller hierarchy. When you say child, you mean as in [b addChildViewController:A]? No navigation controller stack?

Comment: yes - addChildViewController:A no navigation controller stack involved - this is an ios 6.0+ app

Comment: With the deep hierarchy and all needing to talk to each other, this sounds like a high degree of coupling, not uncoupling to me. If that can't be redesigned, then I think I would go for notifications. I think that would lead to a lot cleaner code.

Comment: they're all behind independent protocols and use delegates to pass messages so they're actually pretty decoupled. The hierarchy imposes a chained dependency but it doesnt really care about the type of controller responsible for doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is an interesting question, but I guess we need few hints, such as a scheme.
 The first thought is why you need to add nested child? couldn't you manage using a simple stack and a single Container VC? It seems to be not correct how you manage your VCs. If they need to be notified about changes in the model, it should be only the visible to catch them, in the viewWill/Did/appear of the others you can ask fresh data again. If you need to inform each VC about their states, I think you should modify your hierarchy. 
I imagine a Container VC with a stack or a set of VCs and visible VC propery. This Container will manage the exchange of info. As rdelmar said, it seems a really high degrees of coupling. You should rethink in way that sees communication only between container and visible VC, the others can refresh their data while they appear.

Comment: yes - so basically i think we will settle with the a primary container viewcontroller which child view controllers upto a depth of 1 and no more. This basically borrows from Android's equivalent design where single activity plays the role of communicating between the fragments that it hosts

Comment: Exactly. The approach should be taken similar as in UINavigationViewController or UITabbarViewController. The Container controller keeps consistency between the other VCs. You should take a look here is really well explained  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html